# Am I blocked? I am getting am image with a fish

Tags: support

When I click the button to post question I am getting an image with a fish.
It is a drawing.

And I cant post the question.

Am I not allowed to post?

Comment: Depending on how fast (copy-paste from a text editor)/slow (so slow that the connection to SE server has lost and assumed an instant post) you wrote the question, you might encounter captcha since the system suspects something... fishy.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably stumbled on https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/captcha which wants you to verify you're a human. It doesn't seem like things are totally broken for you since you were able to post here on Meta.

You should get a [Captcha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) problem to solve - if you aren't seeing it, maybe this is an issue with your browser? Maybe an issue with accessing the site on mobile?

If you can provide some more details maybe we can help further, or you could try to submit a support ticket to SE.